# matching and displaying the contents of a textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a form containing 6 groupboxes, each containing 180 textboxes, which are in turn divided into three sets: item, description and quantity. i need to match the set of textboxes containing the items, to see which items have been repeated more than once, and to sum up the quantities of the matched items, match it against the available stock and if the sum is greater, to display this in a msgbox, showing the item which will fall short from the available items. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how I might get started; it would involve iterating through each control in the groupboxes to see if they match-up. Probably a more elegant way, but its a start. In this example, I have a messagebox show when there is a match and it concatenates the two values; for your purposes you would want to add your sum function and other code at the time of matching:

```
    Dim myControl As Control

    For Each myControl In Me.GroupBox1.Controls

        If (TypeOf myControl Is TextBox) And myControl.Text <> "" Then

            For Each Control In Me.GroupBox2.Controls

                If (TypeOf Control Is TextBox) And Control.Text <> "" Then

                    If Control.Text = myControl.Text Then

                        MessageBox.Show(Control.Text & myControl.Text)

                    End If


                End If



            Next



        End If

    Next
```